# Path Tracing Striped Reflection

Tags: c++, graphics, raytracing

[Striped Reflections Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biGdl.png)
The reflections of my Path Tracer is looks accurate but has variations in shading which gives it a striped effect. To my understanding, the problem is coming from the large differences between the Wi and Wo vectors that I use in my BRDF. More notably when I hard code the normalization factor in my BRDF it seems to remove the striping, but I can't deduce where the problem is coming from.

Brdf Calculations:

```
Vector3f m = (wo + wi).normalized();
float distribution = D(m, N, material.roughness);
float geometry = G(m, N, wi, wo, material.roughness);
Vector3f fresnel = F(material.Ks, wi.dot(m));
Vector3f numerator = distribution * geometry * fresnel;
// Hard coding this removes the striping.
float denominator = 4 * std::abs(wi.dot(N)) * std::abs(wo.dot(N));
final_color = numerator / denominator;
```

I call EvalBrdf which in turn starts the BRDF calculations in two places. In the explicit light phase and implicit light phase.

In the explicit phase I randomly get a point on a random light(In my project there is only light)and I trace a ray towards that point and check for any intersections of the ray to the random point on the light. This calculations comes down to PdfLight / GeometricFactor(initial intersection, Random light point). All lights are spheres. This ray produces the Wi vector I use in my brdf calculations and the Wo is simply the inverse ray of the prior iterations Wi vector.

PdfLight Calculation:

```
float Scene::PdfLight(Sphere *Q)
{
  return 1.0f / ((4.0f * pi * Q->radius_ * Q->radius_) * ray_time-
>light_list_.size());
}
```

Geometric Factor:

```
float GeometryFactor(IntersectionData &A, IntersectionData &B)
{
  Vector3f D = A.point_ - B.point_;
    return std::abs((A.normal_.dot(D) * B.normal_.dot(D)) / (D.dot(D) * 
(D.dot(D))));
}
```

The second time is when I'm extending the ray path as normal when there hasn't been an non-intersection or an intersection to a light.

Finding the new ray directions after intersection.

```
float cos = float(uniform_random(RNGen));
float phi = float(uniform_random(RNGen));
phi = 2.0f * pi * phi;
Vector3f m = SampleLobe(N, std::pow(cos, 1.0f/(roughness + 1)), phi);
final_sample = 2 * (wo.dot(m)) * m - wo;
```

Sample lobe

```
float s = std::sqrtf(1 - c * c); // sinTheta
Vector3f K(s * std::cosf(phi), s * std::sinf(phi), c);
Quaternionf q = Quaternionf::FromTwoVectors(Vector3f::UnitZ(), N);
return q._transformVector(K);
```

From there I use the Wi and Wo to calculate the color contribution to my object using the previously mentioned BRDF calculation.

I'm not sure what I'm misinterpreting here, but any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.